# ProgressBar in Subthread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I need to write a WPF-Assembly with only a progressbar and a cancel button. This gui has to run in a subthread, so that a program calling the Assembly (sending progress values and checking the cancel state) won't be blocked. I know how to do this the other way around via Backgroundworker, but not how to run a gui in a subthread and communicate between the two threads. Any help appreciated.

Class that starts the gui thread:

```
public ProgressBar()
{
    StartProgressWindowThread(0);    
}

private void StartProgressWindowThread(int numberProgressBars)
{
    progressThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ThreadStartPoint)); 
    progressThread.IsBackground = true;
    progressThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    progressThread.Start(numberProgressBars);
}

private void ThreadStartPoint(object args)
{
    progressBarWindow = new ProgressBarWindow(args);
    progressBarWindow.OnCancel += new EventHandler(CancelAction);
    progressBarWindow.Show();
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
}
```

Update:
At the moment I am sending messages from the calling class to the gui thread via NamedPipes and then invoke the sent values. The cancel button on the gui is connected through a delegate. This works fine, but I am not sure if the NamedPipes are the right choice.

Comment: Provide code for what you *are* able to do, so that we're not re-doing the work that you already have so far, and clarify specifically what aspect of your solution you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Invoke:

```
Invoke(new Action<object>((args) =>
{
    // update gui from a different thread

}), e.Argument);
```